# Convert local TIME_STAMP to UTC time

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

I have two tables with time stamps

`TABLE1` with TIME_STAMP in local time

`TABLE2` with TIME_STAMP in UTC

I need to do something like

```
    select count(*) from TABLE1 where TIME_STAMP > TABLE2.TIME_STAMP
```

The problem is that this app will be deployed in multiple time zones so I cannot use the following

```
    SELECT CONVERT_TZ(TABLE2.TIME_STAMP,'EST','UTC')
```

because '`EST`' can be any time zone.

Is there a way of getting local time zone code and substituting it as second argument?
Or is there a better and more direct approach to solving my issue?

NOTE: Both TABLE1 and TABLE2 TIME_STAMPS have to remain as local and UTC respectively as they are externals that I have no control over...

Comment: My system refused EST & UTC, but worked with -05:00 and +00:00. Thanks: CONVERT_TZ('$time_selected_GMT_for_storage','-05:00','+00:00')

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the solution I implemented:

This will convert NOW from local timezone to UTC 
    `SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' )`

This will convert any given TIMESTAMP string from local timezone to UTC 
 
    `SELECT CONVERT_TZ( "2012-02-14 16:44:36", @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' )`