# How to convert java.sql.Timestamp value from EST to UTC timezone

Tags: java

I have a `java.sql.Timestamp` variable in local timezone with following formatting

`2011-07-21 00:40:37`

I need to convert it to UTC

[I asked this question to see if it can be done by mysql, but received no answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794299/convert-local-time-stamp-to-utc-time)

I guess I have to somehow do it in java code before substituting it in the query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609360/converting-local-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp-in-java

Already asked.

Comment: @Jon That won't work for me because it doesn't take into account the variable DST. This code will be deployed in multiple timezones and I will need it to be accurate in UTC conversion based on its location and time of year...

Comment: MySQL solution `SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Joda Time to parse the timestamp.  You'll need to set the timezone to EST and then get the UTC time from there.  You could do the same thing with the generic Java Date, but Joda is easier to work with.

Comment: Is there a way to read local timezone? EST was just an example, but it could be any timezone

Comment: After a closer look at Joda time I see it has `public long convertLocalToUTC(long instantLocal, boolean strict)` Looks like setting the strict argument to True will make it account for DST if applicable. Hopefully it will turn out to be exactly what I need. Won't know for sure until after QA's done